# There is a way to automatically generate roxygen2 @param tag for a function

Tags: r, roxygen2

Currently if I want to document a function, for example the simple one below

```
a_func <- function(x, y, z) {

}
```

I have to manually type the following @param tag to annotate each of the parameters

```
@param x type, some description
@param y type, some description
@param z type, some description
```

However, when there are a lot of parameters, this approach is extremely error-prone. I could miss some parameters or use the wrong order of the parameters. So I want to ask whether there is a way to let roxgen2 to automatically generate the @param tags based on the names and the order of parameters.

Comment: Have a look at the *Insert roxygen skeleton* shortcut, that when the cursor is placed within a function, places such boilerplate. The default windows shortcut is `Ctrl+Alt+Shift+R`. If you reuse parameters across functions, check the `@inheritParams` tag